# UIStackView with custom size elements and item in the center - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, uistackview

I want to set a UIStackView with 3 views to the bottom of my so that the centre view is positioned in the centre and the other views are adjusted accordingly, I want also to be able to set the width and height anchors for all 3 views.
This is the desired outcome:

[image: Outcome]

This is what I'm getting:

[image: Desired Outcome]

This is the code I'm using:

```
bottomStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [pickerView, downloadContentButton,  shareButton])
    bottomStackView.alignment = .center
    bottomStackView.distribution = .fill
    bottomStackView.axis = .horizontal
    bottomStackView.spacing = 5
    bottomStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bottomStackView)
    
    bottomStackView.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
    bottomStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    bottomStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    pickerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
    shareButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    shareButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    downloadContentButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    downloadContentButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    
    shareButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    shareButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
```

Comment: If you are going to dictate absolutely the height and width of the views and the spacing between them, what is the purpose of the stack view?

Comment: I wanted to implement it because of the change in screen size in different devices

Comment: But if the sizes and spacing are absolute, what difference will screen size make?

Comment: To put it another way: so suppose the screen size changes; what is it that should change about your views? Because, as you have it, nothing can and nothing will.

Comment: Lets say I set my views [width:80]-30-[width:30]-30-[width:80], if the screen size changes the spacing between the views (in this case 30) needs to change. I wanted the stackView to calculate how much to space it

Comment: Ok good answer, so what changes is the spacing. I’ll show you how to do that, hang on a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are after this kind of thing:

[image]

Or, if we get wider:

[image]

If that's the idea, then one key mistake is when you say:

```
bottomStackView.distribution = .fill
```

You actually want `.equalDistribution`. To demonstrate, I created the example entirely in code, so you can see all the settings:

```
let sv = UIStackView()
sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(sv)
sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
sv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true

sv.distribution = .equalSpacing
sv.alignment = .center

let v1 = UIView()
v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
v1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
v1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
v1.backgroundColor = .red
sv.addArrangedSubview(v1)

let v2 = UIView()
v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
v2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
v2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
v2.backgroundColor = .yellow
sv.addArrangedSubview(v2)


let v3 = UIView()
v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
v3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
v3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
v3.backgroundColor = .blue
sv.addArrangedSubview(v3)
```